# Yii - Setting an attribute of one model from the value of an attribute of a different model

Tags: php, yii

I am attempting (and have tried different ways) to grab the attributes of one model to use them to set the attributes of a different model.

I have a "nodes" model that has a few attributes that are needed to go into the "bounce log" model.  However I keep getting the error "Trying to get property of non-object".  I do not understand this error, I am under the impression $node is in fact an object at the time it is being used.

Here is the code:

#### NodeBouncerController.php

```
//..
public function actionConfirm($id) {
        $node = new Nodes("nodesearch");
        $node->unsetAttributes();
        $model = Nodes::model()->findAllByPk($id);
        $node = $model;

        $logmodel = new BounceLog("logsearch");
        $logmodel->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        print_r($_GET);
        if (isset($_GET['BounceLog']))
            $logmodel->attributes = $_GET['BounceLog'];
        if (!isset($node, $logmodel)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("The node was not found.");
        }
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        $this->performAjaxValidation($logmodel);

//This is where I tried various methods to see what would work

        if (isset($_POST['BounceLog'])) {
            $logmodel->attributes = $_POST['BounceLog'];
            $logmodel->setAttribute('node_Geolocation', $node->url);
            $logmodel->node_Name = (string)$node->name;
            $logmodel->node_Type = (string)$node->node_type;
            $logmodel->whenBounced = time();
            $logmodel->whoBounced = "Test User";
            if ($logmodel->save())
                $this->redirect(array('log'));
        }
        $this->render('view', array('model' => $this->loadModel($id), "logmodel" => $logmodel));
    }
//...
```

---

### Models

#### Nodes.php attributes

```
//...
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'url' => 'Url',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'node_type' => 'Node Type',
            'last_bounced' => 'Last Bounced',
            'isonline' => 'Online',
        );
    }
//...
```

#### BounceLog.php attributes

```
//...
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => '#',
            'node_Name' => 'Name',
            'node_Type' => 'Type',
            'node_Geolocation' => 'Geolocation',
            'whoBounced' => 'Who Bounced',
            'whenBounced' => 'When Bounced',
            'reasonBounced' => 'Reason Bounced',
        );
    }
//...
```

---

Please be aware my company uses Yii v1.1.8.r3324

I am still new to Yii and PHP but I have a better grasp on it than I did a few weeks ago.  I just do not understand why this particular need is not working as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trying to get property of non-object` this means that instead of object you get other type of variable.

1. You get nodes with method `findAllByPk` which return array of objects or empty array if where were no results. If table with nodes have unique PK then you must use `findByPk`, it will return null on empty or object.
2. Then you check whethere variablise isset `!isset($node, $logmodel)`. This function only determine if a variable is set and is not NULL. As $node get empty array or array with objects and $logmodel is always object this check is unusefull.

Solution 1

```
public function actionConfirm($id){
    $node = Nodes::model()->findAllByPk($id);
    if ( empty( $node ) ) { // empty will determines that returned array isn't empty
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The nodes was not found.');
    }
}
```

Solution 2. (As of you pointed `node not found` not nodes and has error about non object access)

```
public function actionConfirm($id){
    $node = Nodes::model()->findByPk($id);
    if ( $node === null ) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The nodes was not found.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed to the "findByPk" and it worked for me. Thank you!